# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465 error

Tags: java, android, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send an email with attachemetnet using smtp connction with gmail user name. But I'm unable to send the email and Im getting the following error message.

> javax.mail.MessagingException:Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   smtp.gmail.com, port: 465

Also i have tried with 587 and 25 ports as alternatives. But I'm getting the same exception.

Here is my code.

```
  public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

   private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
    }

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients,
                                      String fileName) throws Exception {
        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            //DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain", fileName));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);

            // Create the message part
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            // Fill the message
            messageBodyPart.setText(body);

            // Create a multipar message
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            // Set text message part
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Part two is attachment
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileName);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Send the complete message parts
            message.setContent(multipart );
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is JSSEProvicer Class

```
public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the code I'm calling to connect smtp server.

```
GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("email.username@gmail.com", "password");
                sender.sendMail("Report - " + storeName, supplierPaymentsSummery,
                        "email.username@gmail.com", "srinivas@gmail.com",
                        directory.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName);
```

Please suggest me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: why don't you try changing `mail.smtp.port` ?

Comment: You could try to download a client email like Thunderbird and try to connect to this smtp url, and check if this credentials work.  If they work, then there is some problem in your code.  If they fails, there is an error with your credentials.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna What Should I change to?

Comment: @Seenu69 it may be happened because of firewall or ISP is blocking that port. So I want to suggest for searching an alternatives..